# What is the working behaviours of "Use default partitioner" in KAFKA Log appender

Tags: kaa

What is the difference If "Use default partitioner" option of KAFKA log appender is set as "True" or "False"?

As per my observation
If this option set as "True" then client program works fine other wise it causing some issues to send the log data.

Do i requires any configuration in "KAFKA" or some where else if i set this options as "False"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If useDefaultPartitioner is 'false' ProducerRecord will be created and sent to a specified topic and partition. The partition to which the log record will be sent calculated based on Kafka log event record and partitionCount.
Details you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/server/appenders/kafka-appender/src/main/java/org/kaaproject/kaa/server/appenders/kafka/appender/KafkaLogEventDao.java#L102-L108) of the Kafka log appender.

You should refer to the [Apache Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation) for details about topics and partitions.